# How do I Normalize PowerShell WebRequest Results?

Tags: powershell, twitter

This issue is related to data produced by Chrome DevTools.

```
1. Sign in to your twitter account.
2. Open dev tools, click on the filter icon, type "TweetDetail".
3. Visit the link containing the video or photo: https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1684529654743330817.
4. Right click the link that appears then Copy >> Copy as PowerShell.
5. Add " | select Content | FL" (without quotes) right after -ContentType "application/json" on the last line.
6. Paste the whole code to PowerShell.
```

The result is containing strange code:

```
�:Y��(�����?[R:W�8^��9S♣C3▼@�QYd1►��8 jE��і:�B*�☻t�jRY��Ц8+F�z*��
          �B��2_�\�
          A���2
          g�s�ģ�# �}�^�
          }�'@�SL]l^1ꕟ��X↨��3▲k���V��,ܤC��2����L→$��↓�☻7����r���4�1aT{��D§K�Ćh�bS(‼u"!RU▲�      ∟��Ɂҁ/�B�☺♠B�J"�ȢW��)
�~C�J��eҀ<<�]�▼�@���hgvM|��ږQ��ٶ��������Z♺�t§V���=���
          �☺�Klkr�♦���p�azK"3I¶�)��,n�չ]�!�#���y�:��▬�W �'ы1���Yr��"�������ͣ��|∟ma�Y*b�^��MomHݶm(�kG��s�♦���,|<��9д♦�����5�[☺qO�Χ�☺,��)�ȍ���ڃ����O���U�tQ��{��f�
          ���^�p�ā��!g?.‼�E���j�}�.X�S�
ٙ�9BS�[�fy▬��a�-�D��D��=��W↑�t��↕�QP�Vt�&*�̣j�:�:�►���>4�◄�♦��<��;�4C|�������Z��▼m↔� 9��ߺҁ|�,[����▬�.
          ����h�^\�ʠQ�w�☻�ڊҺ���s��e��R^�m��b���&����3s�?.G�y��Y_♦����h�7>�m1�.�O��|�v���j��`7♥�w`���
          W�m}8���3Ze_� �E↔♦%}y↕b6)t�;��߳�m�‼h+�▼���?f�

..........
```

If the status does not contain videos or photos, [like this one](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1711788684243046525), then the results can be read normally:

```
Content : {"data":{"threaded_conversation_with_injections_v2":{"instructions":[{"type":"TimelineAddEntries","entries":[
          {"entryId":"tweet-1711788684243046525","sortIndex":"7511583352611729282","content":{"entryType":"TimelineTime
          lineItem","__typename":"TimelineTimelineItem","itemContent":{"itemType":"TimelineTweet","__typename":"Timelin
          eTweet","tweet_results":{"result":{"__typename":"Tweet","rest_id":"1711788684243046525","has_birdwatch_notes"
          :false,
..........
```

So, how do you make sure that the results of the request for the 1st URL are the same as the results of the request for the 2nd URL?.

**NB:** In the Linux terminal, `Copy as cURL (bash)`, both links produce normal character output, aka readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is compressed, because the request you copied has an `Accept-Encoding` saying that you can accept compressed data.

I don't think Invoke-WebRequest has any support for that, so the easiest method might be to opt out by setting the header's value to `"identity"`, always requesting non-encoded data.